# Easy way to make an unsigned char larger than 256? So it can be converted to an Integer

Tags: c++, char, int

Is there any way to increase the size of an unsigned char so that it can be casted into an integer of a size greater than that?

UPDATE:

Basically i'm editing an exsisting system in which a port number was defined as an unsigned char as they only needed number up to 255. Now it needs to be increased to any port number, so i'm trying to find an easy way of increasing the size without having to go through 100's of files changing references etc..

Comment: Sorry, edited my question to give it a reason!

Comment: An `unsigned char` can hold only 256 different values, period. If you want more than that, you'll have to use another type or add another variable to hold the extra info...

Comment: You're gonna have to do it the hard way this time and manually change it everywhere. But while you're at it, create a typedef in a header and include this header in all the files that need to use the port number. So, in the future, if port number needs to be 32-bit or 64-bit you can simply change the typedef.

Comment: @EitanT there are plenty of platforms where `CHAR_BIT > 8`... not that that would help the OP

Comment: Looks like this is going to take a while then! Well, thanks for the help, was worth a try! Haha

Comment: @EitanT Yes it does, but it does not mandate how many bits are present in a char. Implementations could have 64-bit chars too, but `sizeof(char)` would still be reported as 1. You have to inspect the `CHAR_BIT` macro in `climits` to know how many bits are in a char.

Comment: @Prætorian The OP states that `char` holds 8-bits. Am I wrong?

Comment: @EitanT No you're not, but that's not what the argument is about. You kept claiming that the standard mandates `sizeof(char) == 1` to support your original statement *An unsigned char can hold only 256 different values, period.* That is simply not true, there are plenty of platforms out there that can hold more than 256 values in a char, and sizeof(char) doesn't have anything to do with that.

Comment: @Prætorian I stand corrected then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't change the size of built in type.

But you can cast `unsigned char` to `int` first and change it later:

```
unsigned char val = 25;
int int_val = val;
int_val = 1000;
```

**According to question update**

I think the only option is to change the type manually. But before changing make a `typedef` and use it:

```
typedef int PortId
```

and replace `unsigned char` with `PortId`

Comment: Yeah looks like it'll be a manual job! Oh well, was worth a try!

Answer (score 3):

The c++ standard tells that the size of char is to be 1.

However, you can use typedefs, and then it is easy to change the size :

```
typedef unsigned char data_type;  // 1 byte
```

to

```
typedef unsigned short data_type; // 2 byte on some platforms
```

Comment: If you really want it to be 2 bytes, you need `uint16_t`, not `short`.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1 byte, but it could be a 64-bit byte

Comment: @JonathanWakely in this case, it's been made clear in the question that it is an 8-bit byte.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes but the point is that the number of bits in a char is what's relevant, saying "size of char is 1" is irrelevant.

Comment: @JonathanWakely The point is that it is simple to change the type using typedef. Using `uint16_t` instead of `short` is a minor nit.